# Multithreading to crawl large volume of URLs and download

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I've been using `multithreading` to do this, however it hangs up a lot. I was thinking about `multiprocessing`, but I am not sure if that is any more advantageous.

I have a series of names, and for each name a range of dates. I spawn a thread for each date in the range and then do work inside. Once work is complete, it puts result into `Queue()` for `main` to update the GUI.

Is using a `Queue()` to hold desired URLs better than starting say, 350 threads, at once and waiting? Python seems to hang when I start that many threads.

Comment: 350 threads is a lot. Consider a process or thread pool. `pool.map_unordered` implements a return queue you can use to feed the gui

Comment: @tdelaney for `pool.map_unordered` are we talking multiprocessing `Pool()`?

Comment: how many total requests are we talking about here?

Comment: `multiprocessing.Pool` is multiple processes. The same interface is implemented as a thread pool at `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`. Subprocesses achieve much better parallelism but there is a cost to passing data back and forth. If you have significant processing and relatively small return data, it is the better choice.

Comment: @tdelaney If I am going to these urls and downloading 20-65MB files, is this still the best method?

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that threads are better at waiting (I/O bound work) and multiprocessing is better at cpu bound work. It would seem threading/green-threads are the way to go. Check out the [aiohttp](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library, or may I suggest [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) which runs on the twisted framework which is async. Either of these (especially scrapy) will solve your problem. But why reinvent the wheel by rolling your own when scrapy has everything you need? If scrapy seems to bloated for your use case, why not use the non-block request tools provided in aiohttp using python 3.* async/await syntax?

Comment: Limited by 2 things: We get Python 2.7 from ArcGIS, and we cannot have any additional modules imported other than standard ones. Work limitations suck! However, I am looking at the `multiprocessing.Pool` method to take a chance on it.

Comment: You want multithreading if you are just fetching urls, just use the `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Spawning 350 processes just doesnt sound practical for a bunch of I/O bound work.

Comment: By "fetching" we are going to the URL, and downloading anywhere from 20-65MB files. Is multithreading the way to go?

Comment: @pasta_sauce unless you are also doing some significant processing of those files in the thread, I would say yes. Downloading is essentially waiting